How to Start a New Blockchain from a Specified Block State After a Host Function Failure?
I'm working on a blockchain that experiences a host function failure at block 100. To address this, I plan to initiate a new chain using the state from block 999. What methods or best practices are available to transition to the new chain from the specified block state (block 999)?
